# SSIS PACKAGE UTILITY CREATION

Tags: ssis

AIM: I need to create an SSIS Utility. This package reads the excel file and import the file data to a remote SQL server DB.

Things Done: I have created an Integrated Services package and am able to import the data to SQL DB. The package is working fine and all tasks are executing successfully in Visual Studio. I have added the screenshot below.
[Package in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjCJJ.jpg)

I am not getting the method to make this Utility as an executable file. Such that the user just double clicks and the utility will be executed. Also, I need to make the Excel file location(Source file) dynamic. Please help me to provide some suggestions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way built into SSIS to automatically build an executable package.  You will need to build a console app that launches the package.   You can find plenty of examples of how to launch an SSIS package from an application on the internet.